# How do I isolate certain characters in cell content of an excel to new cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

---

**How do I isolate certain characters in cell content of an excel to new cell**

*Example: I have a big paragraph of information wrapped in a cell and I need to separate only few characters of that data to a different cell*

_Example: 
`A1: hflsjdflknsdlfjlkfkjdlfjwelkjA-123456789ad,fbbdsfsdbfndsafnsadfndfn`

I need to isolate `A-123456789` to adifferent cell_

Comment: Welcome to Super User! As is, this question is too broad for a simple answer. You need to specify what criteria you want to use to identify the substring to extract. For example, is the substring always a certain length? Does it always start at a certain index? Does it match a specific text pattern? These are details necessary to give you an answer that is useful for your particular case because different criteria require different methods. Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/916414/edit) your question to include this missing information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With your data in **A1**, in **A2** enter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1,9999)
```

and in **A3** enter:

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1)
```

[image]

Of course these can be combined into a single formula:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1,9999),FIND(",",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1,9999))-1)
```